# How can I put a std::hash::Hasher within a Box?

Tags: rust

I have a data structure that looks something like this:

```
pub struct X<K> {
    hasher: Box<std::hash::Hasher>,
    phantom: std::marker::PhantomData<K>,
}
```

And this is used as follows:

```
impl<K: std::hash::Hash> Trait<K> for X<K> {
    fn function(&mut self, key: &K) -> usize {
        ...
        key.hash(&mut *self.hasher);
        ...
    }
}
```

I am getting the following compiler error in the nightly:

> The trait `std::hash::Hasher` is not implemented for `std::boxed::Box<std::hash::Hasher + 'static>`

Another approach is to use `key.hash(self.hasher.deref_mut())`, which triggers the following error:

> `std::hash::Hasher + 'static` does not have a constant size known at compile-time

Both errors are in the `hash` call. I find it strange that `std::hash::Hasher` is not implemented for `Box`, but I wonder if this is not something done to protect me from myself. Aside from that, it seems weird that the `deref_mut` error complains about size known at compile time, considering that the `Box` *should be* a fixed size structure.

I know that a way to fix this would be to use a template parameter, but I am avoiding this since `X` will be used in other data structures which wouldn't need the parameter, and that would mean I would have to pass around an unnecessary parameter. It seems that this is the approach taken by `HashMap`, as it uses the `RandomState` template parameter, but I would prefer to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Use a generic: `X<K, H>`, as you said. You can provide a default for the hasher e.g. `struct X<K, H = SipHasher>`, so that users of it don't have to provide it.

Comment: Ah. I think I realised what you meant. You wanted an existential type, so you can still vary the implementation and not have to pass that argument around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I find it strange that `std::hash::Hasher` is not implemented for `Box`

I assume you mean for `Box<T> where T: std::hash::Hasher`. I don't know why it wouldn't be implemented, but it's probably just because no one has yet.

> it seems weird that the `deref_mut` error complains about size known at compile time

The problem is that the generic type `H` has the implicit `Sized` bound (everything does by default):

```
fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H)
    where
        H: Hasher;
```

You'd need it to say:

```
fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H)
    where
        H: ?Sized + Hasher;
```

Again, I don't see any reason it couldn't be changed to do this, it's just most likely that no one needed it to.

---

You can add a newtype to work around the problem:

```
use std::hash;

pub struct X<K> {
    hasher: BoxedHasher,
    phantom: std::marker::PhantomData<K>,
}

struct BoxedHasher(Box<hash::Hasher>);

impl hash::Hasher for BoxedHasher {
    fn finish(&self) -> u64 {
        self.0.finish()
    }

    fn write(&mut self, bytes: &[u8]) {
        self.0.write(bytes)
    }
}

impl<K> X<K>
where
    K: hash::Hash,
{
    fn function(&mut self, key: &K) -> usize {
        key.hash(&mut self.hasher);
        0
    }
}
```